# Does the Hadwiger-Nelson graph have a perfect matching?

Tags: graph-theory, real-analysis, matching-theory, perfect-matchings

The *Hadwiger-Nelson graph* on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is defined to be $(\mathbb{R}^n,E_n)$ where $$E_n = \big\{\{x,y\}: x,y\in \mathbb{R}^n \text{ and } |x-y|=1\big\},$$ where $|\cdot|$ denotes the Euclidean distance in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

For $n>1$, is there a [matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)) $M\subseteq E_n$ such that $\bigcup M = \mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: There are $2^{\aleph_0}$ vertices and each vertex has degree $2^{\aleph_0}$ so can't you just do it by transfinite induction?

Comment: So every graph on $\kappa$ vertices such that every vertex has degree $\kappa$ has a perfect matching where $\kappa$ is infinite? (It may be obvious but I dont see it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find such a perfect matching on $\mathbb R$, by taking the pairs $\{x,x+1\}$ whenever $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is even. Next, you can put a copy of this matching on every parallel translate of some line in $\mathbb R^n$ to get a perfect matching in $E_n$.